# for some reason only one item can be inserted into my queue and my display function doesn't work

Tags: c++, queue

I need to create a queue that holds two type of objects (Video and Music) that are derived from a parent class(Media). My print function isn't working and my enqueue function isn't working as well

This is the file that holds the media class. Media is the parent class for two child class called Video and Music.

```
#include <string>

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#ifndef Lab6Final_Media_h

#define Lab6Final_Media_h

class Media
{

  public:

   //public member functions

     Media(){}// Class constructor

     string getTitle(); //returns the title

     int getLength(); //returns the length

     void setTitle(string title);

     void setLength(float length);

     virtual void display(){} //prints the title and length info*/

  protected:

     float length;

     string title;

 };

 void Media::setTitle(string input) 

  { 

    title = input;

  }

 void Media::setLength(float input)

  {

    length = input;

  }

 string Media::getTitle()

  {

    return title;

  }

 int Media::getLength()

  {

    return length;

  }

 #endif
```

This file hold the child class Music.

```
   #include <iostream>

   #include "Media.h"

   #include <string>

   using namespace std;

   #ifndef Lab6Final_Music_h

   #define Lab6Final_Music_h

   class Music: public Media
   {

    public:

        Music();

        void display();

   };

   Music::Music()

   {


   }

    void Music::display()

   {

      cout<<"Song: "<<title<<" "<< length;


    }


   #endif
```

This file holds the Video class.

```
 #include <iostream> 

 #include "Media.h"

 #include <string>

 using namespace std;

 #ifndef Lab6Final_Video_h

 #define Lab6Final_Video_h

 class Video: public Media

 {

  public:

       Video(){}

       void display();

 };

 void Video::display()

  {

     cout<<"Video: "<<title<<" "<< length;

  }

#endif
```

This is my que file.

```
#include <iostream>

#include <string>

#include "Music.h"

#include "Video.h"

using namespace std;

#ifndef Lab6Final_quetype_h

#define Lab6Final_quetype_h

class queType

  {

    public:

       queType(int max);

       queType();

       void Enqueue(Media* newitem);

       Media* Dequeue();

       bool IsEmpty() const;

       bool IsFull() const;

       void displayQue();

   private:

       int front;
       int rear;
       Media* items[20];
       int maxQue;
 };

#endif

queType::queType(int max)`

{

  maxQue = max + 1;`

  front = maxQue - 1;`
  rear = maxQue - 1;`

}

  queType::queType()
 {

    maxQue = 501;

    front = maxQue-1;

    rear = maxQue - 1;

 }

  bool queType::IsEmpty() const

// Returns true if the queue is empty; false otherwise.

  {

   return (rear == front);

  }

  bool queType::IsFull() const

// Returns true if the queue is full; false otherwise.`

{

return ((rear + 1) % maxQue == front);

}

void queType::Enqueue(Media* newItem)

// Post: If (queue is not full) newItem is at the rear of the queue;

//       otherwise, a FullQueue exception is thrown.

{

if (IsFull())

    throw "is full";

else {

    rear = (rear +1) % maxQue;

    items[rear] = newItem;

    }

}

Media* queType::Dequeue()

// Post: If (queue is not empty) the front of the queue has been

//       removed and a copy returned in item;

//       otherwise, an EmptyQueue exception is thrown.

{

if (IsEmpty())

{

   cout<<"is empty\n";

    Media* emptyMedia = NULL;

    return emptyMedia;

}

else

 {

    front = (front + 1) % maxQue;

    return items[front];

 }

}

void queType::displayQue()

{

  for(int i = 0; i<10; i++)

   {

     items[i]->display();

     Dequeue();

   }

}
```

Comment: Too much code.  Please provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I noticed that your media class has length as a float, you set it as a float but your getter is returning an int. Is this what you are after? If so you should cast the value. If not you need to change the declaration of your getter function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I have a series of classes that will do what you are asking for. The Media class is an abstract type where both Music & Video are derived from it. There is a Queue class that does only what a queue is supposed to do. Then I have introduced a new class MediaManager which is basically a wrapper around a queue member variable, but you can also add other functionality to this class that manages the media objects without having to modify the Queue class. There is no need for the AudioManager to implement the structure and functionality of a queue object or container. I Also restructured your header file guards to be defined as the filenames themselves, but I encapsulated all of the classes that pertain to your lab work within a namespace. I do no recommend the concept of `#using namespace std;` in a global space or even within the main function! It is considered bad practice for it can cause many headaches later on so anything that has to deal with the standard library I use the std namespace with the scope resolution operator. I also use modern c++ concepts such as `nullptr` for null pointers, `explicit` for constructors taking only 1 parameter or constructors that have multiple parameters with default values that can result in a single argument being passed in, `sealed` after a class name that will not be inherited from, `override` on pure virtual methods in derived classes that are inheriting from an abstract data type, member initializer lists where applicable, and many others.

**stdafx.h**

```
#ifndef STDAFX_H
#define STDAFX_H

#include <tchar.h>
#include <conio.h>

#include <memory>

#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

enum ReturnCode {
    RETURN_OK = 0,
    RETURN_ERROR = 1,
}; // ReturnCode

#endif // STDAFX_H
```

**stdafx.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
```

**Media.h**

```
#ifndef MEDIA_H
#define MEDIA_H

namespace lab6 {

class Media {
public:
    enum MediaType {
        MT_MUSIC = 0,
        MT_VIDEO,
    }; // MediaType

protected:
    std::string m_title;
    float       m_length;

private:
    MediaType m_type;

public:
    void setTitle( const std::string& title );
    std::string getTitle() const;

    void  setLength( float length );
    float getLength() const;

    MediaType getType() const;

    virtual void display() = 0; // Purely Virtual Each Derived Class Must Implement Their Own

protected:
    explicit Media( MediaType type ); // Protected Constructor
    Media( MediaType, const std::string& strTitle, float length = 0 );

}; // Media

} // namespace lab6

#endif // MEDIA_H
```

**Media.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Media.h"

namespace lab6 {

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Media()
Media::Media( MediaType type ) :
m_type( type ),
m_length( 0 ) {
} // Media

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Media()
Media::Media( MediaType type, const std::string& strTitle, float length ) :
m_type( type ),
m_title( strTitle ),
m_length( length ) {
} // Media

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// getType()
Media::MediaType Media::getType() const {
    return m_type;
} // getType

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// setTitle()
void Media::setTitle( const std::string& title ) {
    m_title = title;
} // setTitle

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// getTitle()
std::string Media::getTitle() const {
    return m_title;
} // getTitle

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// setLength()
void Media::setLength( float length ) {
    m_length = length;
} // setLength

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// getLength()
float Media::getLength() const {
    return m_length;
} // getLength

} // namespace lab6
```

**Music.h**

```
#ifndef MUSIC_H
#define MUSIC_H

#include "Media.h"

namespace lab6 {

class Music : public Media {
public:
    Music();
    explicit Music( const std::string& strTitle, float length = 0 );
    virtual void display() override;

}; // Music

} // namespace lab6

#endif // MUSIC_H
```

**Music.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Music.h"

namespace lab6 {

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Music()
Music::Music() :
Media( MT_MUSIC ) {
} // Music

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Music()
Music::Music( const std::string& strTitle, float length ) :
Media( MT_MUSIC, strTitle, length ) {
} // Music

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// display()
void Music::display() {
    std::cout << "Song: " << m_title << " Length: " << m_length << std::endl;
} // display

} // namespace lab6
```

**Video**

```
#ifndef VIDEO_H
#define VIDEO_H

#include "Media.h"

namespace lab6 {

class Video : public Media {
public:
    Video();
    explicit Video( const std::string& strTitle, float length = 0 );

    virtual void display() override;    

}; // Video

} // lab6

#endif // VIDEO_H
```

**Video.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Video.h"

namespace lab6 {

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Video()
Video::Video() :
Media( MT_VIDEO ) {
} // Video

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Video()
Video::Video( const std::string& strTitle, float length ) :
Media( MT_VIDEO, strTitle, length ) {
} // Video

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// display()
void Video::display() {
    std::cout << "Video: " << m_title << " Length: " << m_length << std::endl;
} // display

} // namespace lab6
```

**Queue.h**

```
#ifndef QUEUE_H
#define QUEUE_H

namespace lab6 {
// ----------------------------------------------
// Queue - Cicular Array Style Queue
template<class T>
class Queue {
public:
    static const int s_maxSize = 100;

private:
    T m_queue[s_maxSize];
    int m_front;
    int m_back;

public:
    Queue();

    T front();
    T back();

    void push( T item );
    void pop();

    bool isEmpty() const;
    bool isFull() const;

}; // Queue

#include "Queue.inl"

} // namespace lab6

#endif // QUEUE_H
```

**Queue.inl**

```
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Queue()
template<class T>
Queue<T>::Queue() :
    m_front(-1),
    m_back(-1) {
} // Queue

  // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // front()
template<class T>
T Queue<T>::front() {
    if (m_front == -1) {
        std::ostringstream strStream;
        strStream << __FUNCTION__ << " Error: can not return front of an empty queue.\n";
        throw strStream.str();
    }
    return m_queue[m_front];
} // front

  // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // back()
template<class T>
T Queue<T>::back() {
    if (m_back == -1) {
        std::ostringstream strStream;
        strStream << __FUNCTION__ << " Error: can not return back of an empty queue.\n";
        throw strStream.str();
    }
    return m_queue[m_back];
} // back

  // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // push() - enqueue
template <class T>
void Queue<T>::push(T item) {
    if (isFull()) {
        std::ostringstream strStream;
        strStream << __FUNCTION__ << " can not add to queue. It is full.\n";
        throw strStream.str();

    }
    else if (isEmpty()) {
        m_front = m_back = 0;

    }
    else {
        m_back = (m_back + 1) % s_maxSize;
    }

    m_queue[m_back] = item;
} // push

  // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // pop() - dequeue
template <class T>
void Queue<T>::pop() {
    if (isEmpty()) {
        std::ostringstream strStream;
        strStream << __FUNCTION__ << " can not remove item from queue. It is already empty.";
        throw strStream.str();

    }
    else if (m_front == m_back) {
        m_front = m_back = -1;

    }
    else {
        m_front = (m_front + 1) % s_maxSize;
    }
} // pop

  // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // isEmpty()
template<class T>
bool Queue<T>::isEmpty() const {
    return (m_front == -1 && m_back == -1);
} // isEmpty

  // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // isFull()
template<class T>
bool Queue<T>::isFull() const {
    return (m_back + 1) % s_maxSize == m_front ? true : false;
} // isFull
```

**Queue.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Queue.h"

namespace lab6 {
} // namespace lab6
```

**MediaManager.h**

```
#ifndef MEDIA_MANAGER_H
#define MEDIA_MANAGER_H

#include "Queue.h"

namespace lab6 {

class Media;

class MediaManager sealed {
private:
    Queue<Media*> m_queue;

public:
    MediaManager();

    void    addToQueue( Media* item );
    void    removeFromQueue();

    Media*  getFront();
    Media*  getBack();

    bool    isEmpty() const;
    bool    isFull() const;

    void    displayQueue();

}; // MediaManager

} // namespace lab6

#endif // MEDIA_MANAGER_H
```

**MediaManager.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "MediaManager.h"

#include "Media.h"

namespace lab6 {

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// MediaManager()
MediaManager::MediaManager() {
} // MediaManager

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// addToQueue()
void MediaManager::addToQueue( Media* item ) {
    m_queue.push( item );
} // addToQueue

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// removeFromQueue()
void MediaManager::removeFromQueue() {
    m_queue.pop();
} // removeFromQueue

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// isEmpty()
bool MediaManager::isEmpty() const {
    return m_queue.isEmpty();
} // isEmpty()

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// isFull()
bool MediaManager::isFull() const {
    return m_queue.isFull();
} // isFull

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// getFront()
Media* MediaManager::getFront() {
    return dynamic_cast<Media*>( m_queue.front() );
} // getFront

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// getBack()
Media* MediaManager::getBack() {
    return dynamic_cast<Media*>( m_queue.back() );
} // getBack

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// displayQueue() -- Written For Array Style
void MediaManager::displayQueue() {
    if ( isEmpty() ) {
        std::cout << "The Queue is empty!/n";
        return;
    }

    while ( !m_queue.isEmpty() ) {
        m_queue.front()->display();
        m_queue.pop();
    }

} // displayQueue

} // namespace lab6
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include "Music.h"
#include "Video.h"
#include "MediaManager.h"

int main() {
    using namespace lab6;

    try {
        // Create MediaManager First
        std::unique_ptr<MediaManager> pMediaManager;
        pMediaManager.reset( new MediaManager );

        // Create A Few Media Items
        Music m1( "Wouldn't it Be Nice", 3.40f );
        Music m2( "My Eyes Adore You", 4.20f );
        Music m3( "Comfortably Numb", 6.8f );

        Video v1( "Shawshank Redemption", 142.5f );
        Video v2( "Matrix", 148.2f );
        Video v3( "Lord of the Rings: Fellowship Of the Ring", 190.5f );
        Video v4( "Lord of the Rings: The Two Towers", 188.4f );
        Video v5( "Lord of the Rings: Return of the King", 191.2f );

        // Now Add these to the Manager which encapsulates the queue
        pMediaManager->addToQueue( dynamic_cast<Media*>( &v3 ) );
        pMediaManager->addToQueue( dynamic_cast<Media*>( &v4 ) );
        pMediaManager->addToQueue( dynamic_cast<Media*>( &v5 ) );
        pMediaManager->addToQueue( dynamic_cast<Media*>( &m2 ) );
        pMediaManager->addToQueue( dynamic_cast<Media*>( &v2 ) );
        pMediaManager->addToQueue( dynamic_cast<Media*>( &m3 ) );
        pMediaManager->addToQueue( dynamic_cast<Media*>( &v1 ) );
        pMediaManager->addToQueue( dynamic_cast<Media*>( &m1 ) );

        // Now as A Test Will Get Both The Front Then The Back
        std::cout << "Display Front & Back Of Queue" << std::endl;
        pMediaManager->getFront()->display();
        pMediaManager->getBack()->display();
        std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;

        // Now Will Will Show Full Queue Which Will Also Pop The Queue As It Goes Through the List
        std::cout << "Display Entire Queue: " << std::endl;
        pMediaManager->displayQueue();
        std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;

        // Now Our Queue Should Be Empty
        std::cout << "Is Queue Empty: " << std::endl;
        std::cout << (pMediaManager->isEmpty() ? "true" : "false") << std::endl;
        std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;

        pMediaManager.reset();

    } catch( const std::string& str ) {
        std::cout << "Exception Thrown: " << str << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Press any key to quit." << std::endl;
        _getch();
        return RETURN_ERROR;
    } catch( ... ) {
        std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << " Caught Unknown Exception" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Press any key to quit." << std::endl;
        _getch();
        return RETURN_ERROR;
    } 

    return RETURN_OK;
} // main
```

**Results**

[image]

Comment: If you have any questions please feel free to leave a comment. If you would like I can also show a queue class that is a Linked List Type. This Queue class should operator O(1) - linear! It doesn't care about its size! You can also easily inherit from this Queue class to make it a priority queue class but you may have to write your own sort function to sort the items according to their priority, maybe a swap function, a few comparison operators and maybe an equal operator.

Comment: THANK YOU! I greatly appreciate this

Comment: @CesaSalaam Not a problem at all. Helping others with their troubles helps to strengthen my own skills. The only thing that I ask is if this has helped you please like or up vote and if it answered your initial question please accept this as a correct solution to your problem. :)